# Storage limit error for database

Tags: 2013, storage

I received this error, is it pertaining to the size of the list or the entire site itself?
how can I get additional space?

[image: enter image descriptionddd here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your site collection has exceeded the storage capacity defined in Central Administration by your admins. You either need to delete files to get under the quota to be able to add new content, or have your SharePoint Administrators increase the quota for your site collection.

If you need to see what is causing you to eat up space, you can visit the `/_layouts/15/storman.aspx` to see what lists and libraries are consuming the most space.

Comment: https://cloudsites.vzbi.com/sites/jppdatabase/_layouts/15/storman.asp didn't work.... also how can I check to see how much space I have or does the admin have to do that?... I am currently the site owner as well

Comment: @Raymound it's aspx in case you missed the x.

Comment: what can I do to reduce the space.

Comment: Delete files from your libraries that are no longer needed, empty the recycle bins, reduce version settings are all ways to free up sapce.